# Отсортировать массив 2 * N элементов

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка, структуры-данных

Необходимо отсортировать массив. Есть N, необходимо создать массив длинной в 2 * N элементов таким образом: **a1, aN + 1, a2, aN + 2, a3, AN + 3, ... aN, a2 * N;**

Входной массив:

**0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9**

Результат после сортировки:

**0 5 1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9**

Проблема задачи в том, что использовать дополнительные массивы запрещено. Можно использовать только переменные типа ***int tmp***;

Пытался сделать такое, но удается лишь добиться такого успеха:

**0       5       1       6       3       7       2       8       4       9**

Задача вообще для перекомпоновки списков на СИ, но с массивами почти также. Не могу дойти до правильного алгоритма самостоятельно. Заранее спасибо!

UPD: Мой код для списка:

```
void CHANGE_STRUCT(int n) {

List *P = BegL;
List *Pk = BegL;
List *Pl = BegL;
int tmp;


for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    Pk = Pk -> link;
}

Pl = Pl -> link;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    P = P -> link;
    Pl = Pl -> link;
    tmp = Pk -> A;
    Pk -> A = P -> A;
    P -> A = tmp;
    tmp = Pl -> A;
    Pl -> A = Pk -> A;
    Pk -> A = tmp;
    Pk = Pk -> link;
    Pl = Pl -> link;
    P = P -> link;
}
printf("\nNew struct\n");
PRINT_STRUCT();}
```

Comment: Так все же — список или массив? список-то перекомпоновать куда проще... просто берем нужный элемент с номером n+1 и далее и переносим куда надо. С массивом так просто не получится...

Comment: Вообще необходимо список. Он может быть как односвязный так и двусвязный. Я пробовал сделать с односвязным. Элементы после N (5,6,7,8,9) становятся идеально, а с а1 до N уже проблема. Не вижу правильного решения. Например если N <= 3, то с моим решением всё работает, а дальше уже живет своей жизнью.

Comment: С двусвязным проще :) - не надо держать лишние переменные.

Comment: Со списком ведь будет действительно проще. Я ведь могу не переставлять элементы таким образом, а сделать иначе: я могу после а1 сделать вставку aN+1, а потом удалить старый aN + 1. Правильно?

Comment: Не "вставить-удалить", а "перенести". Например, у вас некий `a`, после которого надо вставить некий `p`. Вытаскиваем его из его старого места, типа `p->prev->next = p->next; p->next->prev = p->prev;` (конечно, надо проверять, не конец ли это списка с той или иной стороны — на NULL), а потом поместить в новое место типа `p->next = a->next; p->prev=a; a->next->prev = p; a->next = p;`. Где-то так. Еще раз — нужны проверки на концах списка. И идти не индексами, а указателями...

Comment: Для односвязного списка нужно хранить два указателя — на текущий элемент и предшествующий, так как в односвязном не получится сделать настройку a la `p->prev->next = p->next;`... Словом, немного терпения и аккуратности :), и всё получится. С массивом так легко не отделаешься...

Comment: Спасибо! Классная задача и для списков и для массивов.

Answer (score 1):

В C односвязные списки можно редактировать передавая в функции адрес поля `next` в предыдущем узле. Так работает `insert`, который вставляет новый узел в начало списка. Так работает `cut`, который срезает голову списка и возвращает её. `reorder` использует два бегущих указателя - для первой и для второй половин списка. Узел указываемый вторым указателем вырезается и вставляется после узла указываемого первым.

Обратите внимание на нотацию: если функция не меняет список, она вызывается с указателем на голову списка: `print(head)`. Если функция меняет список, она вызывается с указателем на указатель на голову. Голова может поменяться, это необходимо: `insert(&head, ...)`. Про функцию `reorder` известно что она не меняет голову списка, её можно было бы вызывать как `reorder(head, ...)`. Проявляем твёрдость, добавляем ещё один уровень косвенности: `reorder(&head, ...)`. Нотация.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_t node_t;
struct node_t {
    int value;
    node_t *next;
};

void insert(node_t **head, node_t *node) {
    assert(node->next == NULL);
    node->next = *head;
    *head = node;
}

node_t *cut(node_t **head) {
    node_t *node = *head;
    *head = (*head)->next;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void reorder(node_t **head, int n) {
    node_t **n1 = head;
    node_t **n2 = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        n2 = &(*n2)->next;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        n1 = &(*n1)->next;
        insert(n1, cut(n2));
        n1 = &(*n1)->next;
    }
}

void print(node_t *head) {
    printf("[ ");
    for (; head != NULL; head = head->next) {
        printf("%d ", head->value);
    }
    puts("]");
}

int main() {
    node_t *head = NULL;
    for (int i = 9; i >= 0; --i) {
        node_t *node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        node->value = i;
        node->next = NULL;
        insert(&head, node);
    }
    print(head);
    reorder(&head, 5);
    print(head);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция `move_to` по индексу определяет где должен оказаться элемент с этого индекса. Если её последовательно применять в цикле `i = move_to(i)`, окажется что индексы бегают по циклу. В этом цикле все числа надо переставить на следующую позицию (`rearrange_loop`). Чтобы не обрабатывать цикл несколько раз (что испортит результат) он обрабатывается только тогда когда встречен первый раз (`fresh_loop`).

Алгоритм квадратичный - это плата за неиспользование дополнительной линейной памяти. Есть ли способ решить без дополнительной памяти за линейное время для данной конкретной перестановки - не знаю.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int move_to(int n, int i) {
    if (i < n) {
        return 2 * i;
    } 
    return 2 * i + 1 - 2 * n;
}

bool fresh_loop(int n, int i) {
    for (int j = move_to(n, i); j != i; j = move_to(n, j)) {
        if (j < i) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void rearrange_loop(int n, int i, int a[/* 2n */]) {
    int v = a[i];
    for (int j = move_to(n, i); j != i; j = move_to(n, j)) {
        int tmp = a[j];
        a[j] = v;
        v = tmp;
    }
    a[i] = v;
}

void rearrange(int n, int a[/* 2n */]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; ++i) {
        if (fresh_loop(n, i)) {
            rearrange_loop(n, i, a);
        }
    }
}

void print(int n, int a[/* 2n */]) {
    printf("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    puts("]");
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    print(5, a);
    rearrange(5, a);
    print(5, a);
}
```